# Assigning NSOutputStream value via. NSURLConnection

Tags: java, objective-c

I have a Java code like this...

```
OutputStream os = null;
URLConnection conn = null;
conn = getConnection(url, fileSize,index, size,fileId, fileName); //this method's return type is URLConnection
os = conn.getOutputStream();
os.write(buf); //buff is a byte array 
os.flush();
```

I'm writing this code in Objective-C and I have a problem in assigning NSURLConnection object to NSOutputStream. Can anyone help me to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

See Apple's documentation [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001836-BAJEAIEE). The technique isn't as straightforward, but the docs are thorough.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer. I followed this document to make the initial connection before and that is working fine. The only problem that I have here is to make the output stream with the assigned values pf the NSURLConnection object and append the bytes that I have already read to the buf as the body.

Comment: Perhaps I don't understand the question, but the guide shows how to do this. NSURLConnection doesn't have an output stream; rather, it takes a delegate which it calls every time it receives data (see especially the connection:didReceiveData: message). Inside the delegate you can append the data to an NSMutableData object (or anything else you want), until the download is completely finished. See in particular Listing 3 and 5.